# Why can't you return a variable that has been initialized inside the function

Tags: java

In java if I have initialized a variable in a function that returns an that variable at the end, why can't I return that function?

Here's the some sample code, that I was working

```
  private int spitNumber(int imgNum) {
      int returnNum;
      switch (imgNum) {
      case 1:
      case 14:
      case 27:
      case 40:
      returnNum = 1;
      break;

      case 12:
      case 25:
      case 38:
      case 51:
      returnNum = 12;
      break;

      case 13:
      case 26:
      case 39:
      case 52:
      returnNum = 13;
      break;

    };
    return returnNum;
  }
```

When I compile the code I get the error message

```
error: variable returnNum might not have been initialized
    return returnNum;
           ^
```

Comment: Change to int returnNum = 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `switch` but your switch does not cover all the cases.

Think when `imgNum = 100`, what value will your program assign to `returnNum`?

Nothing, right?

So you should initialize a starting value for `returnNum` or provide a `default` case for `switch` and assign your `returnNum` value there

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I thought that having a default case wasn't necessary but I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have any default case. the message shown says that the variable might not have been initialized, if your value is not among the handled cases.

Answer (score 0):

Need to initialize the variable at the beginning of your code.

Example :
     int returnNum = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types like `int`, for example, cannot be `null`. You must initialize it.